# How to get only current events using Eventbrite.net API wrapper

Tags: .net, api, eventbrite

I am using this .NET API Wrapper, http://penguinboy.github.com/Eventbrite.NET.

After trying the sample codes, which had been converted to VB.net:

```
    ' Create the context object with your API details
    Dim context = New EventbriteContext("Replace with APP Key", "Replace with User Key")

    ' Instantiate Organizer entity with the desired organizer ID
    Dim organizer = context.GetOrganizer(Replace with Organizer ID)

    ' Get all the events that the organizer has created
    Dim events = organizer.Events.Values

    ' Get the first event in the collection
    Dim firstEvent = events.First()

    ' All the attendees in that event
    Dim attendees = firstEvent.Attendees

    ' All the tickets in that event
    Dim tickets = firstEvent.Tickets.Value
```

The organiser.event.values will return me all the past and current events. Currently, I use a loop to go through the events list but if the organizer has a lot of events created then the http request may take a long of time to process.

Is there any methods that could provide the ability to get just the current events only?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `user_list_events` API and pass in `event_statuses=live` to return only live events.

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/

I don't know exactly how this .NET wrapper is implemented, but you'll need to find the appropriate method which calls `user_list_events` and pass in both `event_statuses=live` and `user=users@emailaddress.com` for the user you are interested in.  If you are trying to get your *own* events, you can leave out the `user` argument and by default your events will be returned.